# Problema al actualizar estilos según valor en la tabla

Tags: css, angular6, table

Estoy creando en angular una tabla en la cual muestra los registros de BBDD correctamente.

```
<app-table
      #tablaConsulta
      class="d-flex flex-column h-100 consulta"
      [items]="consultaSource"
      [showIndex]="false"
      counterName="{{ 'consulta' | translate }}"
      [columnsData]="[
        {
          title: 'tipo',
          property: 'TIPO'
        },
        {
          title: 'estado' ,
          property: 'ESTADO',
        },
        {
          title: 'movil',
          property: 'TELEFONO_MOVIL'
        },
        {
          title: 'fecha' ,
          property: 'FECHA',
          type: 'Date',
          format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
        },
        {
          title: 'hora',
          property: 'HORA'
        }
      ]"
      (selectedOption)="handleSelectedOption($event)"
      >
    </app-table>
```

Ahora, me gustaría poder establecer estilos en función del valor del estado que recibo. Sé que con angular material se puede de una manera más sencilla, pero tal y como está estructurada la tabla, ¿a alguien se le ocurre cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola, ¿usas algún componente externo para generar la tabla o lo estás haciendo todo de 0? Si lo estás generando todo desde 0, lo más sencillo es crear una función en tu componente y ahí le pasas el row, y del row, podrás obtener el estado... Y con ésto, ya aplicas la clase css que deseas. En un par de horas te puedo ayudar mejor, ahora estoy liado

Answer (score 0):

Angular tiene dos formas sencillas de seleccionar la clase a usar sobre un elemento:

```
<tr [class.MiClase]="valorBooleano"> ... </tr>

<tr [ngClass] ="{MiClase: valorBooleano, MiOtraClase: otraCondicion()}"> ... </tr>
```

La primera es un `on/off` para una clase, la segunda funciona con varias. Además, la segunda se puede reescribir como:

```
export class AppComponent {
  valido: boolean = true;

  otraCondicion() {
    return ... && ...;
  }

  aplicarClases() {
    let classes = {
      MiClase: this.valido,
      MiOtraClase: this.otraCondicion();
    };
    return classes;
  }
}

<tr [ngClass]='aplicarClases()'> ...
```

Comment: Buenas Pablo, 
Gracias por tu aportación, pero o no es válida en mi código o no sé cómo aplicarla. El problema con el que me encuentro es que no puedo tratar cada fila como elemento independiente para así poder usar la directiva ngClass como bien pones. 
Yo llamo a un servicio del back y guardo su respuesta en la variable en consultaSource que es la que paso a la tabla en **[items]="consultaSource** y con la arquitectura de tabla, automáticamente se rellena, con el mismo estilo para todo.

Comment: He puesto tr como ejemplo, pero se lo puedes aplicar a cualquier otro elemento HTML (table, div ...)